# Sending email with multiple attachments (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, email, email-attachments

I am wanting to send an email with multiple excel attachments.
The below code has func to create each file and save in a created user directory.
The files are saved fine.
The email is generated and sends fine.

My one issue that I cannot solve is: It is attaching TWO copies of each file, causing the email to have two sets of attached data.

**The issue seems to be in the func configuredMailComposeViewController.**

Can someone please help me fix the code so it will only send a single set of files?

```
class ExportToExcel: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var taskArr = [Export]()
var task: Export!
var noteID:Int = -1
var contactID:Int = -1
var companyID:Int = -1

let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()

var fileNameNote = String()
var fileNameCompany = String()
var fileNameWC = String()
var fileNameBldg = String()
var fileNameCurrent = String()
var fileNameLoss = String()

fileprivate var contactDetails: ContactModel = ContactModel()
fileprivate var companyDetails: ContactModel = ContactModel()
fileprivate var quickNoteDetails: QuickNoteModel = QuickNoteModel()
fileprivate var bizDetails: BizDetailsModel = BizDetailsModel()
fileprivate var imageNames: Array<PhotoModel> = [PhotoModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // creating the "MeetingNotes" directory
    self.createNewDir()
    
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposer.delegate = self
                
    self.sendEmailButton()
}

func setFileLocation(_ fileName: String) -> URL {
    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    let dirPaths = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let docsURL = dirPaths[0].appendingPathComponent("MeetingNotes")
    let path = docsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    
    return path
}

func createNewDir() {
    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    let dirPaths = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let docsURL = dirPaths[0]
    let newDir = docsURL.appendingPathComponent("MeetingNotes").path
    do {
        try filemgr.createDirectory(atPath: newDir,
                    withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func createNoteCSV() -> Void {
    
    fileNameNote = ("\(task.Company_Name)-\(task.Note_Date)-Note.xls").removeSpaces

    let path = setFileLocation(fileNameNote)

    var csvText = "Note Date,Note Details,Company Name,Company Phone,Contact Name,Contact Office,Contact Mobile,Contact Email,Coverages,BOP SIC,NAICS\n"
    
    let newLine = "\(task.Note_Date),\(task.Notes.removeCommas),\(task.Company_Name),\(task.Company_Phone),\(task.Contact_Name),\(task.Contact_Office),\(task.Contact_Mobile),\(task.Contact_Email),\(task.Coverages),\(task.BOP_SIC),\(task.NAICS)"
            
        csvText.append(newLine)
    do {
        try csvText.write(to: path, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let url = path
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url as Any] , applicationActivities: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to create file ")
        print("\(error)")
    }
}

func createBldgCSV() -> Void {
    if !BuildingsArrayExport.array.isEmpty {
        fileNameBldg = ("\(task.Company_Name)-\(task.Note_Date)-Bldg.xls").removeSpaces

        let path = setFileLocation(fileNameBldg)

        var csvText = "Note Date,Company Name,Bldg Nickname,Bldg Address, Bldg City, Bldg State, Bldg Zipcode,Deductible,Bldg Year,Office SqFt,Bldg SqFt,Floors,Roof Type,Construction Type,Bldg Type,Bldg Value,Yr Heat Replaced,Yr Wire Replaced,Yr Roof Replaced,Yr Plumbing Replaced,Pct Bldg Occupied,Pct Tenant Occupied,Pct Sprinkler,Responible for Parking lot,Alarm Type\n"
        
        let items = BuildingsArrayExport.array
        for item in items {
            let address  = "\(item.address1) \(item.address2)"
            let newLine = "\(task.Note_Date),\(task.Company_Name),\(item.nickName),\(address.removeCommas),\(item.city.removeCommas),\(item.state),\(item.zipCode),\(item.deductible.removeCommas),\(item.buildingYr),\(item.officeSqFt),\(item.buildingSqFt),\(item.buildingStories),\(item.roofType.removeCommas),\(item.constructionType.removeCommas),\(item.buildingType.removeCommas),\(item.buildingValue.removeCommas),\(item.heatingReplaced),\(item.wiringReplaced),\(item.roofReplaced),\(item.plumbingReplaced),\(item.percentUnoccupied),\(item.percentOthersOccupied),\(item.sprinklerSystem),\(item.responsibleForParkingLot),\(item.alarmType)\n"
                    
                csvText.append(newLine)
        }
        do {
            try csvText.write(to: path, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let url = path
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url as Any] , applicationActivities: nil)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to create file ")
            print("\(error)")
        }
    } else {
        return
    }
}

     // more of the same func types, but deleted to reduce post size


func sendEmailButton() {
    
    guard appOwnerEmail != nil else {
        return
    }
    self.createNoteCSV()
    self.createCompanyCSV()
    self.createBldgCSV()
    self.createWcCSV()
    self.createLossCSV()
    self.createCurrentCSV()

    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController(appOwnerEmail)
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}

 // During this function, it will post all data twice.  This includes 
 // 2 x each xls and 2 x each image.
 // The "do" portion of this func gets executed twice.  
 // That is the issue

func configuredMailComposeViewController(_ email: String) -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    mailComposer.setSubject("\(task.Company_Name) meeting note")
    mailComposer.setMessageBody("Meetings note details)", isHTML: true)
    mailComposer.setToRecipients([appOwnerEmail])
    mailComposer.setCcRecipients([""])
    mailComposer.setBccRecipients([""])

    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    let dirPaths = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                in: .userDomainMask)
                
    do {
        
        let fileNoteURL = setFileLocation(fileNameNote)
        let attachmentNoteData = try Data(contentsOf: fileNoteURL)
        mailComposer.addAttachmentData(attachmentNoteData, mimeType: "application/xls", fileName: fileNameNote)

        let fileCompanyURL = setFileLocation(fileNameCompany)
        let attachmentCompanyData = try Data(contentsOf: fileCompanyURL)
        mailComposer.addAttachmentData(attachmentCompanyData, mimeType: "application/xls", fileName: fileNameCompany)

        if !BuildingsArrayExport.array.isEmpty {
            let fileBldgURL = setFileLocation(fileNameBldg)
            let attachmentBldgData = try Data(contentsOf: fileBldgURL)
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(attachmentBldgData, mimeType: "application/xls", fileName: fileNameBldg)
        }

        if !WorkersCompArrayExport.array.isEmpty {
            let fileWCURL = setFileLocation(fileNameWC)
            let attachmentWCData = try Data(contentsOf: fileWCURL)
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(attachmentWCData, mimeType: "application/xls", fileName: fileNameWC)
        }

        if !CurrentPolicyArrayExport.array.isEmpty {
            let fileCPURL = setFileLocation(fileNameCurrent)
            let attachmentCPData = try Data(contentsOf: fileCPURL)
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(attachmentCPData, mimeType: "application/xls", fileName: fileNameCurrent)
        }

        if !LossItemsArrayExport.array.isEmpty {
            let fileLossURL = setFileLocation(fileNameLoss)
            let attachmentLossData = try Data(contentsOf: fileLossURL)
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(attachmentLossData, mimeType: "application/xls", fileName: fileNameLoss)
        }

        imageNames = AppDelegate.getUserDatabase().getPhotoList(noteID)
        for imageName in imageNames {
            let name = imageName.name
            let imageURL = dirPaths[0].appendingPathComponent(name)
            let attachmentImages = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                mailComposer.addAttachmentData(attachmentImages, mimeType: "application/jpg", fileName: name)
                mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
                self.present(mailComposer, animated: true
                    , completion: nil)
            
        }

       if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.present(mailComposer, animated: true
                   , completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Emails not configured")
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("We csv encountered error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    return mailComposer
}

func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in })
    self.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true){}
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

public func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
     
    switch result {
    case .cancelled:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case .saved:
        AppDelegate.getUserDatabase().recordEmailSent(noteID)
        print("Mail saved")
    case .sent:
        AppDelegate.getUserDatabase().recordEmailSent(noteID)
        print("Mail sent")
    case .failed:
        break
    @unknown default:
        fatalError()
    }

    controller.dismiss(animated: true) {
         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Way to much code posted, you must have some idea where the issue is so you can narrow it down some for us.

Comment: I can see you are trying to present `MFMailComposerViewController` inside one image for loop while trying to attach each of them. `for imageName in imageNames {`,  inside function `configuredMailComposeViewController(:)` again you are trying to do so from `sendEmailButton()`. can you try to present it only once when you have successfully configured composer attaching everything?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I have updated the above to be more precise on where I believe the issue is.  I added the amount of code I did, as I was not 100% certain where the error is.

Comment: I found the error and it was being caused by a different viewController.  @SauvikDolui, thank you for your input as this did help clean up the code some

Answer (score 0):

I found the error and it was being caused by a different viewController.
I am leaving the code up and lengthy to support someone else who may need help exporting multiple file via email.